# Matplotlib: Create lat/lon white/black round bounding box around basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to change the design of the default frame around my matplotlib map for a lon/lat white and black round 'bounding box' type of frame, where, for example, black extends from 90 degrees W to 45 degrees W, and white from 45W to 0 degrees, etc.

A very similar code was developed for R-users (see: http://menugget.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/add-frame-to-map.html) for a rectangular map but I have not found anything for Python-users.

Does anyone know if there is a package in Python that allows for that type of frame design?

Below is my code for plotting Antarctica in python. The figure below the code shows the R equivalent of what I want to achieve.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11.7,8.3))

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05,right=0.95,top=0.90,bottom=0.05,wspace=0.15,hspace=0.05)
ax = plt.subplot(111)

x1 = -180
x2 = 180
y1 = -90
y2 = 90

m = Basemap(projection='spstere', llcrnrlat=y1,urcrnrlat=y2,llcrnrlon=x1,urcrnrlon=x2,boundinglat=-63,lon_0=180, resolution='l',round=True)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,60),labels=[1,1,1,1],linewidth=0.5, fontsize=10, dashes=[1,5])
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,20),linewidth=0.5, fontsize=10, dashes=[1,5])
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.5)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is particularly robust, but it works for your example, and was my first real experience with basemap (have done a bit of mapping before).

```
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge
def draw_round_frame(m, width_percent=0.05, degree=45):
    centre_x = (ax.get_xlim()[0] + ax.get_xlim()[1]) / 2
    centre_y = (ax.get_ylim()[0] + ax.get_ylim()[1]) / 2
    width = abs(centre_x) * width_percent

    inner_radius = abs(centre_x) - width/2
    outer_radius = inner_radius + width

    angle_breaks = list(range(0, 361, degree))

    for i, (from_angle, to_angle) in enumerate(list(zip(angle_breaks[:-1], angle_breaks[1:]))):
        color='white' if i%2 == 0 else 'black'
        wedge = Wedge((centre_x, centre_y), outer_radius, from_angle, to_angle, width=outer_radius - inner_radius, 
                      facecolor=color,
                      edgecolor='black',
                      clip_on=False,
                      ls='solid',
                      lw=1)
        ax.add_patch(wedge)
```

To use just call it just before `fig.show()`

```
draw_round_frame(m)
plt.show()
```

[image: round map frame]

It should probably use the map coordinates more than it does, and it overlaps the axis as I can't currently figure a way of adding more space around the map itself, but might give you an idea to start with.

Comment: Great this is exactly what I was looking for thank you very much Ken!
I adjusted the boundinglat value (from -63 to -62) to get more space between the outlines and the frame, and have shortened the width_percent value for the frame, from 0.05 to 0.02. That does the trick.